# solve the following differential eqaution. $\frac{d \phi(t)}{d t}=-\int_0^t \gamma\left(t-t^{\prime}\right) \phi\left(t^{\prime}\right) d t^{\prime}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integro-differential-equations

solve the following differential eqaution for $\gamma\left(t\right)=e^{-\alpha t } (\alpha > 0) $

$\frac{d \phi(t)}{d t}=-\int_0^t \gamma\left(t-t^{\prime}\right) \phi\left(t^{\prime}\right) d t^{\prime}$
,
$\phi\left(0\right)=\phi_0 $

Can someone please kindly help me? Also is there any specific name for this kind of differential equation problem which I can use for google search keyword to try to find some solution?

Comment: Laplace transform is the way to go. Indeed, the right-hand side is a (truncated) convolution product; it can be mapped to a standard product thanks to this transform.

Answer (score 3):

Differentiating both sides with respect to $t$, one can transform the integro-differential equation
$$
\frac{d }{d t}\phi(t)=-\int_0^t e^{-\alpha(t-t')} \phi(t')\,d t' \tag{1}
$$
into an ODE:
\begin{align}
\frac{d^2 }{d t^2}\phi(t)&=-\phi(t)+\alpha\int_0^t e^{-\alpha(t-t')} \phi(t')\,dt' \\
&=-\phi(t)-\alpha\frac{d }{d t}\phi(t) \tag{2}.
\end{align}
Since $(2)$ is a second order ODE, one needs an additional constant of integration. It can be obtained by taking $t=0$ in $(1)$:
$$
\phi'(0)=0. \tag{3}
$$
The solution of $(2)$ is left as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you for your help. So this means I only need to calculate the following equation?
 {y''(t) + α y'(t) + y(t) = 0, y(0) = Φ_0, y'(0) = 0} 
The wolfram alpha result for this was :
 y(t) = (e^(-1/2 (sqrt(α^2 - 4) + α) t) (sqrt(α^2 - 4) (e^(sqrt(α^2 - 4) t) + 1) + α (e^(sqrt(α^2 - 4) t) - 1)) Φ_0)/(2 sqrt(α^2 - 4)). Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is. ${}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!! Have a nice day!